# Can't find Graphics item in Visual Studio 2012 "Add New Item" dialog

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, windows-phone-8, image-editor

I need to add an image via the Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) *Add New Item* option.  When I activate this option I get the *Add New Item* dialog box.  Under the *Installed* node, I see many different options for the new item type.  However, I do not see the **Graphics** item as specified in this MSDN article:

[Image Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh315744.aspx)

I checked ever node and child node in the New Item pane, including the **Online** node, just in case. Nothing (*see image below)*.  Can someone tell me why I can't find the **Graphics** as a new item type and how to add it to the New Item choice list? The project is a Windows Phone 8 project if that is relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is not available from WP8 projects. But what are you trying to do?

If you are trying to add an existing image then you can just right click your project and choose Add-->Existing Item.. You can open the images in the image editor.

If you are trying to create a new one, a fbx 3d scene for example you can just create a normal console application (Template will be available for you here) add your graphics there and save them. Then you can add them to your WP8 project using Add-->Existing Item..

Comment: I want to use the VS2012 Image Editor directly since the images I am using for my small and medium tiles in the WMAppManifest editor are not showing up when the app is pinned to the start screen.

Comment: Hmm are you not able to open the tile images in the image editor? The tiles are stored by default in /assets/tiles. You can just double click the file to open it in Image Editor. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No I can open up images in the Image Editor.  I wanted to start from a "blank" image in case the images I am opening up have format issues.  That's why I wanted the equivalent of "File->New->Graphics" which as you pointed out, isn't available in a Windows Phone 8 project.

Comment: Yea but you can create a blank image anywhere (for example in Paint, or as I pointed out in a dummy console App) and then just import it to your WP project using Add->Existing Item and work from there.

Comment: True.  Anyways, my Nokia Ambassador found the real problem.  I was using the TemplateIconic Tile Template instead of TemplateFlip.  I switched to TemplateFlip and the problem went away.  I thought Iconic meant static.  It looks like it means the images have to be in Icon file format.  I'm marking your answer as accepted since it was correct in this context.